# Downloading Ubuntu on a flashdrive

Tags: installation, testing

I am using a Windows 7 Home Premium. Please could you provide me step byt step procedures on how I can download Ubuntu onto a flash drive and try it out on my PC before running it?

Answer (score 0):

**Download Ubuntu 13.04:**

[Ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso) (32bit) ([Torrent Download](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso.torrent))

[Ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso) (64bit) ([Torrent Download](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent))

**How to create a bootable USB stick**

To run Ubuntu from a USB stick, the first thing you need to do is insert a USB stick with at least 2GB of free space into your PC.

The easiest way to put Ubuntu onto your stick is to use the USB installer provided at pendrivelinux.com. You’ll need to download and install and follow the instructions.

[**Download Pen Drive Linux's USB Installer**](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)

1. Select Ubuntu Desktop Edition from the dropdown list.
   [image]
2. Click 'Browse' and open the downloaded ISO file.
   [image]
   [image]
3. Choose the USB drive and click 'Create'.
   [image]

[More detailed technical instructions are available on the Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/index.html)

After finish all step, reboot you PC/Laptop and choose **TRY Ubuntu**.